# VS Code setting editor.autoClosingBrackets languageDefined - where are these language settings defined?

Tags: settings, visual-studio-code

[Related issue on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/4360).

VS Code's setting editor.autoClosingBrackets: languageDefined says "Use language configurations to determine when to autoclose brackets".

- Where does VS Code gets this information from?
- Is the "language configuration" referring to language-specific user settings? If so, what setting controls this? If it's the editor.autoClosingBrackets setting that controls this, what's the default behaviour for:

  ```
    [javascript]: {
        "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "languageDefined"
    }
  ```

  Does it force the default behaviour for this language?
- Where can I see a list of all language configurations?

Answer (score 0):

I found this setting when I entered Command Palette(⇧⌘P) and typed "settings", and in the listing select the option "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)", then you can make this setting.

For more informations: [VS Code settings you should customize](https://dev.to/thegeoffstevens/vs-code-settings-you-should-customize-5e75)

My configurations:

```
{
"typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
"explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
"cSpell.userWords": [
    "rxgo"
],
"go.toolsManagement.autoUpdate": true,
"js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators": true,
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always"
},
"angular.enable-strict-mode-prompt": false,
"[typescript, javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
},
"[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
"editor.tabSize": 2,
"javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative",
"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative",
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay"
```

}